# JavaFX WebView throws Exception on resize

Tags: browser, webview, javafx

i load a html File inside a Browser in Webview. it displays it just fine, but if i try to resize the window to its miminal size(less than 200 px height) eclipse throws Exceptions.

my environment:
Linux Suse 12.3, JDK 1.7.0_45, JavaFX 2.2, Compiler Compliance level 1.7.

here is the Code:

```
public class HTMLView extends BorderPane {   
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();   
    public HTMLView(String fileName) {
        webEngine.load(fileName);        
        setCenter(browser);

    }
}
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Info Board</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Serif, Tahoma, Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #330000;
}
.box{
    margin-top:         100px;
    border-top:         1px solid #F3F3F3;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -o-box-shadow:      0 0 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:         0 0 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);    
    padding:        10px;
    background:         #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<img src="logo.png" style="float: right;"/>
<span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Test Test</span>
<ul>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
</ul>
<span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Test Test</span>
<ul>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
<li>Test Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 112622
    at com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPrismGraphics.doDrawMaskTexture(J2DPrismGraphics.java:1124)
    at com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPrismGraphics.drawPixelsMasked(J2DPrismGraphics.java:1010)
    at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$ClipLayer.render(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1267)
    at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.renderLayer(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:174)
    at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.restoreStateInternal(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:191)
    at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.restoreState(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:202)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:67)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint2GC(WebPage.java:661)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:640)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:71)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderForClip(NGNode.java:443)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderRectClip(NGNode.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderClip(NGNode.java:360)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderForClip(NGNode.java:443)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderRectClip(NGNode.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderClip(NGNode.java:360)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:188)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

any idea about the cause of this exception?
Many Thanks